# can't run scripts from cmd line windows for postgresql

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line

I'm in a windows environemnt and kicked off psql. I've tried running -a -f filename.sql and psql filename.sql. This what I keep getting:

```
scala_db-# psql C:/Users/user/Desktop/emps.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql C:/Users/user/Desktop/...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

```
scala_db-# psql C:/Users/user/Desktop/emps.sql;
```

Looks like you already enter into the psql command line.

If so,  you can use meta command \i  to execute the SQL file.

e.g.

```
mydb=# \! echo "select 1" > c:/pgccc/tmp.sql
mydb=# \i c:/pgccc/tmp.sql
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

If you hasn't logged into psql command line, you can use one single psql command line to execute the sql file.
e.g.

```
psql mydb -f c:/pgccc/tmp.sql
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Here the "mydb" is the target database.  If not specified,  you will connect to the default database.

Answer (score -1):

When you run windows cmd

```
psql -U username dbname -f filename.sql
```

username is your user name,
dbname is your database name,
filename.sql is your file